# quotes around __builtins__?

Tags: python, built-in

(Python 3.6, IDLE)    If I type  `dir(__builtins__)` in the shell, I get a lengthy list of exceptions and functions, from 'ArithmeticError' to 'zip.'  But  `dir('__builtins__')` yields a different list of objects, attributes  and functions, many of which appear to be string functions.
What is `dir('__builtins__')` accessing?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Quotes around things are string literals in Python. Strings are just another type of object, the `str` type to be exact. When given an argument, `dir` returns:

> an alphabetized list of names comprising (some of) the attributes
>       of the given object

You passed it a `str` object, so that is why it includes string method names such as `'islower', 'isnumeric', 'isprintable', 'isspace'` etc...

You can pass it any other `str` object and you'll get the same result, try:

```
dir('foo')
```